# How to count the occurances of elements in list in for a row in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df that looks like this. it is a multi-index df resulting from a group-by

```
grouped = df.groupby(['chromosome', 'start_pos', 'end_pos',
                      'observed']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

```
                                          reference         zygosity    
chromosome  start_pos   end_pos observed                                            
chr1            69428   69428       G       [T, T]          [hom, hom]      
                69511   69511       G       [A, A]          [hom, hom]      
                762273  762273      A       [G, G, G]       [hom, het, hom] 
                762589  762589      C       [G]             [hom]       
                762592  762592      G       [C]             [het]
```

For each row i want to count the number of het and hom in the zygosity. and make a new column called 'count_hom' and 'count_het'

I have tried using for loop it is slow and not very reliable with changing data. Is there a way to do this using something like df.zygosity.len().sum() but only for het or only for hom

Comment: Does this work: `from collections imoprt Counter; pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.zygosity.map(Counter)).fillna(0, downcast='infer').set_index(df.index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working on groupby result, you could adjust your `groupby` construction a bit by including a lambda to `agg` that counts "het" and "hom" values for each group at the time you build `grouped`:

```
grouped = (df.groupby(['chromosome', 'start_pos', 'end_pos','observed'])
           .agg(reference=('reference', list), 
                zygosity=('zygosity', list), 
                count_het=('zygosity', lambda x: x.eq('het').sum()),
                count_hom=('zygosity', lambda x: x.eq('hom').sum())))
```

If you want to create a list out of all lists, you could use the following:

```
cols = ['chromosome', 'start_pos', 'end_pos','observed']
out = df.groupby(cols).agg(**{c: (c, list) for c in df.columns.drop('reference')}, 
                           count_het=('zygosity', lambda x: x.eq('het').sum()),
                           count_hom=('zygosity', lambda x: x.eq('hom').sum()))
```

Comment: This works perfectly but the output only contains the columns specified in the aggregate function. I want to keep all the other columns untouched. How to do that?

Comment: @maskedpirate could you explain what you mean by "untouched"? `groupby` aggregates data, so you'll have to "touch" the other columns as well, if you want to keep them.

Comment: sorry what i meant was combining them as a list just like i was doing earlier. and i may not know the names of the columns. so yeah i figures i could still use `agg(lambda x: x.tolist())` along with the additional columns

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with [`List count`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/count):

```
grouped['count_hom'] = grouped['zygosity'].apply(lambda x: x.count('hom'))
grouped['count_het'] = grouped['zygosity'].apply(lambda x: x.count('het'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically count all possible values using `explode` + `groupby`, then `value_counts`, then `unstack`:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df, df['zygosity'].explode().groupby(level=[0,1,2,3]).value_counts().unstack(level=4).fillna(0).add_prefix('count_').astype(int)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
                                       reference         zygosity  count_het  count_hom
chromosome start_pos end_pos observed                                                  
chr1       69428     69428   G            [T, T]       [hom, hom]          0          2
           69511     69511   G            [A, A]       [hom, hom]          0          2
           762273    762273  A         [G, G, G]  [hom, het, hom]          1          2
           762589    762589  C               [G]            [hom]          0          1
           762592    762592  G               [C]            [het]          1          0
```